# Power BI - filter data to current week (week number)

Tags: powerbi

I have a power bi report with a line chart that has a field called 'EventDate'

I need to add a filter on to this report to say 'only get me the days where the EventDate matches this week number'

I **don't** want to display the last 7 days as a relative filter.

I need to do it by this week.

Can anyone help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the week in the relative date filtering and it returns the dates associated with the current week number rather than the last 7 days.

[image: Relative date filtering]

Comment: Wow!! How does it know your working week? Or does it assume Sunday to Saturday

Comment: I think that's what it assumes. Might be different if your regional settings are different? If you want to start on a different day, then you'll need to do a lot more work.

Comment: No that will be fine, I'll check when I'm next at my PC but does it allow this month, last 3 months etc

Comment: Yep. You can do "Show items when the value:" `is in the last` `3` `months`.

Comment: do you know if there is a way to say last week? E.g. Only get the last calendar week?

Comment: Yeah. `is in the last` `1` `calendar weeks` will get just the previous week (not current week).